# What does 'sockets disabled, connection limit reached' mean?

Tags: lighttpd

I am running lighttpd-1.4 on Redhat4 and I got this error when lighttpd crashed:

```
2009-11-13 16:28:41: (server.c.1383) [note] sockets disabled, connection limit reached 
2009-11-13 16:28:53: (server.c.1337) [note] sockets enabled again
```

What does this mean and how can I avoid it?

I have googled it and did not come up with anything useful.

Comment: There is maximum socket connection limit you need to change it

Answer (score 4):

It means you ran out of file descriptors (1024 by default), read the lighttpd performance docs:
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:Performance

Comment: It does not mean you've run out of file descriptors, it means that lighttpd thinks that that the number of connections used has reached or exceeded the setting of max-connections.

There is a different error if you run out of file descriptors.